# What does it mean azure "cost per hour"?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

Microsoft Azure price some of its resources per hour. For example Virtual Machines.

Question is whether pricing if per "running" hour, meaning time the VM is on the air, or as long as this resource is "hired", regardless its state?

Comment: Running at 100% is usually called "CPU-hour".

Comment: See this page...https://www.cloudyn.com/blog/per-cpu-cycle-per-hour-cloud-cost-model/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the VM is powered on, the clock is ticking.

Answer (score 6):

On the pricing page of [Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/) you'll find that although the price estimations for VMs are quoted 'per-hour', the billing is actually charged per-second that the VM is in a Running or Stopped state (this state is achieved by shutting down the VM from the host OS).

The only time that you will not be charged for a Virtual Machine once provisioned is when it is in the Stopped (Deallocated) state which means a 'Stop' command has been executed via the Azure Portal (or via PowerShell / Azure CLI). When your VM is in this state, Azure will deallocate any hardware resources (CPU/Memory) assigned and Dynamic IP addresses will be removed/reallocated for others to use. You will still be charged for any Storage Accounts being utilised from disks and diagnostic information.